# How to encrypt data using the password from User

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask site. It's specifically a note app. At the moment I am storing the user notes as plaintext. That means that anyone with access to the server which is me has access to the notes. I want to encrypt the data with the user password, so that only the user can access it using their password, but that would require the user to input his/her password each time they save their notes, retrive the notes or even updates them. I am hashing the password obviously.

Anyone has any idea how this could be done?

Comment: If you encrypted the notes with the user's password, what would happen if the user changed their password? The answer is the encrypted notes would be lost. Don't use their password. Search for "AES 256 encrypt" to get started. This is a deep subject but there are MANY good answers available on SO to choose from.

Comment: @Chase Wow, that's a loophole I never though of. I have looked at AES 256 but it still needs a key. I want the user to control the key. The user should have all the access. The database just stores gibberish, and only the user key can unlock it. And in the event the user changes password, the gibberish resets to that. Is this even possible or am I looking at something unrealistic. Then how does Google do it with our notes in Keep considering they encrypt things. Is it all stored with a master key and anyone with access to servers could look at the notes?

Comment: Are you trying to encrypt data at rest or actually encrypt the notes so _only_ the user can unlock them? There’s a big difference there. Using a cipher like AES with a universal secret key paired with a per-note (or per-user) invocation vector is sufficient for encrypting at rest. The only way to truly encrypt just for that user only would be to encrypt the data in the browser before it is sent to your app. Universal secret key + unique IV stored next to the ciphertext is pretty standard.

Comment: @Chase Well I am learning things, with python and html. I was just thinking if that would be possible to encrypt the notes so that ony the user can unlock them. And no one else. "Universal secret key + unique IV" <- This method would mean if by chance someone gets hold of the database they know everything.

Comment: Ciphertext + IV can’t decrypt without the secret key, which is not kept in the database. Even if the database is exposed everything still remains safe.

Comment: Ah! That answer a lot of question. Thank you very much. I shall dig deeper into AES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using @Chase suggestion I found a really helpful thread on stackexchange security [Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157422/store-encrypted-user-data-in-database). Anyone wondering about encryption.

Answer (score -1):

Use session to store user information, the Flask-Login extension would be a good choice for you.

Comment: Well, it raises the same problem. It's never a good idea to store user info in session. Anyone with access could see the password and get all of the data from the server.

Comment: You should just store user id in session, password hash should be in database, not in session.